# How to calculate F1 score for tensor flow dataset which is batched and prefetched (multi label image classification)

Tags: python, metrics, tensorflow-datasets, prefetch

This is the code snippet for the datasets

```
train_ds= tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "./tmp/Alzheimer_s_Dataset/train/", validation_split=0.2, subset="training", shuffle=True, seed=1337, image_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE )

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "./tmp/Alzheimer_s_Dataset/train/", validation_split=0.2, subset="validation", shuffle=False, seed=1337, image_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE )

test_ds= tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "./tmp/Alzheimer_s_Dataset/test/", shuffle=False, seed=1337, image_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE ) 
 
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE) 
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE) 
test_ds = test_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`
```

Even though the training accuracy and validation accuracy are around 94%, the model doesn't perform well on test data. I want to see the F1 score and other metrics. How to calculate the F1 score and other metrics for a tf dataset which is batched and prefetched.

I have tried to do custom F1 score calculation and also have tried to use tensorflow-addons for the metrics calculation. Custom f1 score doesn't work properly and when i compile like this

```
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001), loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=4, average='macro', threshold=0.5)])
```

and try to train the model, it always throw an error

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible.